# Unit $ \mathcal{G} \to f_*f^*\mathcal{G}$ or Counit $ f^* f_*\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}$ Isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of ringed spaces. Fix a $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module $\mathcal{G}$ and a $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{F}$.

It is well known that the fuctors $f^*, f_*$ are adjunct via the adjunction formula

$$Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X}(f^*\mathcal{G},\mathcal{F})= Hom_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(\mathcal{G}, f_*\mathcal{F})$$

This gives arise for counit and unit maps

$$c: f^* f_*\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}$$

$$u: \mathcal{G} \to f_*f^*\mathcal{G}$$

of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules (resp $\mathcal{O}_Y$-modules).

My question is if there are some criterions for $X$ when $c$ is an isomorphsim of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules?

(resp " for $Y$ " s.t. $u$ "  )

I have some properies like projectiveness, flatness or similar in mind... if not too effortful I would be glad to references or proof sketches (or maybe short ideas) why it works

sure it suffice to prove the isomorphism on level of stalks

Comment: Just to be sure I understand the question. You are looking a condition on $X$ (and only on $X$ !) such that for all $Y$, all $f:X\to Y$ and all $\mathcal{O}_X$-module the counit $c:f^*f_*\mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{F}$ is an isomorphism ?

Comment: @Roland: I guess that if it depends ***only*** on $X$ then the claim would be too strong to be realized (please correct me if I'm wrong). So it's ok to mention extra conditions also for $Y$ and/or $\mathcal{F}$. For example and the sake of simplicity one extra restriction might be to assume that we want that the desired equality holds only for quasi coherent $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Sorry for my late respond. Yes of course it is too strong to ask a requirement only on $X$. (This would be true iff $X=\emptyset$). But still I don't know what kind of answer you are expecting. There are many sufficient conditions for $c$ (like $f$ being an immersion) or for $u$ (like $f$ being projective with connected fibers) to be an isomorphism, but it would be better to know what kind of conditions you are expecting.

Comment: @Roland: yes exactly these two are the conditions of a kind I'm looking for. I intended in this thread to sum up the "most common" sufficient conditions for this isomorphism. So I was a bit currious if there exist an article/paper which collects these.

Regarding your "immersion" condition do you mean arbitrary immersion or only the open one? For the open immersion the statement can seemingly easily be verified by considering the story on stalks.

Comment: For the closed immersion I'm not sure. I think that here also a local/stalk argument could work since if we have affine morphism $f: Spec(B) \to Spec(A)$ then locally $f_*\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{F} \vert _A$ ...at least if $\mathcal{F}$ qc :) I guess that this argument should work here.

On the other hand do you have a reference for the "projective with connected fibers" criterion?